# Can any aspect of the brightness of Martian twilight be determined by Curiosity's photo of Earth?

Tags: mars, curiosity, earth, magnitude

Curiosity took this [image](https://mars.nasa.gov/resources/5968/bright-evening-star-seen-from-mars-is-earth/?site=insight) of Earth on Jan. 31, 2014, 80 minutes after sunset.

[image]

Stellarium has the Earth >15° above the horizon 80 minutes after sunset on that day.

[image]
With Stellarium indicating the magnitude of Earth is -1.15, can anything about the brightness (or darkness) of the sky be inferred from this information?

Comment: you really are keen on finding this out.

Comment: Yes, I really am.

Comment: from your profile you are writing a sci fi book yes? From what ive gathered twilight is only a tad brighter than night.